# Qooxdoo: Set correct decoration to a Table

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a class that extend from `qx.ui.tabview.Page`. This class, of course, I instance and push it into a `TabView`. Well, this class has a `__table` member (an instance of `qx.ui.table.Table`).

On my Decoration theme class I override `table` and `window` and for both I set `backgroundColor` to `"black"`.

When I run my app, the **windows have the black background, but tables doesn't.**

Some idea to get the override of table decoration work?

Answer (score 0):

Cells in a table are divs, not table cells. Those divs have a background defined. You need to find the appearance theme for table cells, and override whatever holds the background color in the theme you are using. Table alone won't help.

For example, in .../qooxdoo-sdk/framework/source/class/qx/theme/classic/Appearance.js look for "cell". That's where the background color for normal table cells is being computed. It tells you which colors in Color.js you should set to black. But the location might be different in other themes.

Also, for alternate colors in table rows, probably the table implementation does some manual setting under the hood. Look into the framework code, into the table class, and see where "table-row-background-odd" is being used. (Hint: search for all occurences of bgcolOdd in qx.ui.table.rowrenderer.Default). You either set this color also to black in your Color.js, or override the default renderer - see qx.Class.patch() for how you can inject your code into framework classes.